# $H_0$ and $H_1$ of $\chi^2$ test in confirmatory factor analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confirmatory-factor

I am struggling to find a good text on confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) (an [old thread on the topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156717/book-on-structural-equation-modelling-confirmatory-factor-analysis) has little to offer) and so have some basic questions on CFA.

1. What exactly are the null and the alternative hypotheses of the $\chi^2$ goodness-of-fit test in CFA?
2. A factor model postulates a structure in the data. Which (if any) aspects of this structure are ignored by the $\chi^2$ test?

I have found several verbal descriptions of the test in different places, but they do not seem to be precise enough to really answer the question. In addition to your answers, I will appreciate references about CFA from the statistical/mathematical perspective.