# Exhaustive reading of Factor Analysis

Tags: references, confirmatory-factor

I have learned EFA and CFA in SPSS/ AMOS and a basic understanding of why they work (but in a non-mathematical way, which makes me feel I might have some fundamental misconceptions, and hence this question).

I wanted to know what are some good books/ lectures/ notes to learn the theoretical foundations of EFA and CFA, from beginner's to advanced levels of understanding.

I know that might be a lot to learn, I plan to learn it as soon as possible, but would not mind if learning it too quickly is not possible, and would be grateful for resources that take longer to learn too.

I am comfortable with UG level mathematics (in my final year currently).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Book on structural equation modelling/ confirmatory factor analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156717/book-on-structural-equation-modelling-confirmatory-factor-analysis). Books by Mulaik are great. My only problem with them is that they take an algebraic rather than probabilistic perspective. You can learn a lot from them nevertheless.

Comment: It does, thank you for the help!